# This character - ㎜ - raises a UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, python-3.x, gb2312

I am using a Python script to convert files from `gb2312` to `utf-8`. This character messes everything: `㎜` (it is one symbol, not "mm").

```
text = '㎜'
text.encode(encoding='gb2312')
```

raises this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'gb2312' codec can't encode character '\u040b' in position 1: illegal multibyte sequence

I can use workaround by `text.replace('㎜', 'mm')`. But what if there are others such characters? What is wrong with it? Why it is so special?

Is there a way to make Python treat it as any other character?

Comment: You say you're converting from `gb2312` to `utf-8`, but the code you show converts *from* the internal Python encoding (which supports arbitrary Unicode characters), *to* `gb2312`.  This may in fact be your problem, or you might've just showed the wrong part of the code.  Please clarify.

Comment: I just simplified it. It is the same error here. `file_old = open('1.php', mode='r', encoding='gb2312')
file_new = open('2.php', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')

file_new.write(file_old.read())`

Comment: Digging in a bit more, the problem character is `U+339C SQUARE MM`, which is *not* representable in GB2312 per http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/GB2312/list.htm .  Are you *certain* that your input file is actually encoded in GB2312?  And please show us your original script.

Comment: I just noticed that the character in your error message is `U+040B` ( CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER TSHE), not `U+339C`.  There *are* some Cyrillic letters in GB2312 but that's not one of them.  I think we need to see the actual contents of `1.php` -- please upload it somewhere, *unmodified*, and edit a link into your question; *do not* attempt to edit the contents of the file into your question.

Comment: here it is - `http://chengyangxj.com/1.php`. It is just a file with `GB2312` encoding that contains `㎜`.

Comment: For the record, your original script does appear to do the job you say you want to do.  But as a sanity check, if you are on a Linux, OSX, or BSD system, try running the command `iconv -f gb2312 -t utf-8 < 1.php > 2.php` and see what error messages that produces.

Comment: I am on win7-64 now, can't check on other os. I will just hope, that it is the only character that rise this error.

Comment: It is not possible for a file that is actually in GB2312 encoding to contain the character `㎜`, just to be 100% clear.

Comment: @Zack why it is not possible? If you can just create empty file with GB2312 encoding and insert `㎜` into it. Will your computer blow up? )

Comment: It's not possible because GB2312 has no code point for `㎜`.  You can *label* a file containing any byte sequence you want as "encoded in GB2312", but that does not make the label correct.

Comment: @Qiao: No, it won't blow up. You'll get an error as the file no longer is in gb2312.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OK, so, I downloaded the file `1.php` and ran your *original* script on it and I get a *different* error mesage:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gb2312' codec can't decode bytes in position 99-100:
  illegal multibyte sequence
```

The bytes in the file at offsets 99 and 100 are A9 4C in that order.  That is neither a valid GB2312 nor a valid UTF-8 encoding of *anything*.  I suspect you may be in the situation of having a whole bunch of files that are supposedly GB2312 but actually in some other encoding.  If you need to just bull through all such problems, you can use `errors='replace'` and `mode='rU'` (the latter makes Python understand your DOS newlines).

```
file_old=open('1.php', mode='rU', encoding='gb2312', errors='replace')
```

This will insert `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER` in place of anything it can't decode, and continue.  **This destroys data**; first try to figure out what the *real* encoding of the file is.

By the way, don't forget to fix up your HTML header when you're done; the preferred form nowadays is

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Concise, standard compliant, and tested to work all the way back to IE6.

**EDIT:** On further investigation, GB2312 is a character set, not an encoding.  There are several possible encodings of it, but only one allows the two-byte sequence A9 4C: in [Big5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5), it corresponds to the character `呶`.  (I do not know any of the languages that use Chinese characters; does that make more sense in context than `㎜`?)

Python and `iconv` assume that GB2312 is encoded in a different format, [EUC-CN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code#EUC-CN), unless specifically told otherwise.  If I modify your script to read

```
file_old=open('1.php', mode='rU', encoding='big5', errors='strict')
file_new=open('2.php', mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
file_new.write(file_old.read())
```

then it executes without error on the `1.php` you provided.

**EDIT 2:** On *further* further investigation, what *web browsers* do with `<meta charset="gb2312">` is pretend you wrote `<meta charset="gbk">`.  [GBK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK) is a superset of GB2312 that *does* include the `㎜` character.  Python, however, treats GB2312 per its original definition.  So what you really want in order for your conversion to match the original file is

```
file_old=open('1.php', mode='rU', encoding='gbk', errors='strict')
```

Comment: At least `errors='replace'` can save time from messing with `catch except`. html is just random here, only for setting charset for browser showing it right.

Comment: big5 is for traditional hieroglyphs. Can't use it instead of GB2312. `呶` has no connection with `㎜`.

Comment: We should get `㎜` in output file, anything other is not right. But it seams, that only `㎜` has this problem. All files converted successfully after replacing it to `mm`.

Comment: `gbk` is solution! Thank you. That is very useful information.